# What is the meaning of this code?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Ok, I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466952/how-to-get-a-checked-radio-button-in-a-groupbox) and got excellent code example as answer. The code works but I don't understand the meaning of the code. Can someone point the direction for me for further reading in order to understand the code. Here is the code that retrieves the checked radio button in a groupbox:

```
Dim rButton As RadioButton = GroupBox1.Controls _
    .OfType(Of RadioButton)() _
    .Where(Function(r) r.Checked = True) _
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

Ok, the parts that I don't understand are `.OfType`, `.Where`, `.FirsrOrDefault`

**UPDATE:**

Thanks guys, those things are LINQ

Comment: In your previous thread you asked how to replace a bunch of if's and it looks like you have selected.  But what is the point?  Now you know which one is checked, in a different way,  and now...

Comment: @dbasnett: My previous question purpose is to explore if there is a smarter way to check which radio button being checked. And I tried to use the code example given by the answerer. It works and thank-you very much. But I don't understand the code. Specifically I even don't know what is `.OfType` and where it comes from. So, I started this question. Anything wrong from my part?

Comment: No.  My point was now that you know which button is checked what are you going to do.

Comment: @dbasnett: I'm going to ask another question. Here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471695/how-to-calculate-the-total-time-a-user-spending-on-an-application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code selects the first checked radio button in a group of buttons.  Lets walk through the code:

1. `Dim rButton As RadioButton = GroupBox1.Controls _`

   Select the group of form controls
2. `OfType(Of RadioButton)() _`

   But only the Radio buttons from that group
3. `Where(Function(r) r.Checked = True) _`

   That are already checked
4. `.FirstOrDefault()`

   Return the first one or NULL if none are checked.

Comment: Ok, I pick this as answer because it has detailed explanation. I have upvoted all other answers. Many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The code almost reads exactly what it is doing: from the controls on `GroupBox1` that are of type `RadioButton`, take those where the radio button is checked, and then take the first one (or `null` if there aren't any).

In plainer English, among all the radio buttons in the group box, find the first checked one, or return `null` if there aren't any.

The methods come from [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594).

Comment: I mean what is the name/tech of following things: `.OfType, .Where, .FirsrOrDefault` ? I know nothing about those thing and wish to learn it. Can you point to me where to learn more?

Comment: @Predator: These are LINQ methods. LINQ is what you want to read about.

Answer (score 2):

This is the LINQ API for VB.  Basically, each of the methods you mention are selectors and are returning the results of a query.  Check out [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688088) for a ton of examples:

Answer (score 1):

Basically, its going through the controls in GroupBox1 that are **OfType** radiobutton, and **Where** they are checked, grabbing the **First** result or **Default/None** if there are no results.