# Optimised Retrieval of the Checked RadioButton in Relevent GroupBox

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

All, I have a `GroupBox` with multiple controls (`Button`s, `RadioButton`s etc.) and I want to know the most efficent way of establishing which `RadioButton` in the `GroupBox` is in the checked state. I currently have

```
int nCheckedRadioIdx = 0;
foreach (Control ctrl in groupBoxList.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
    {
        if (((RadioButton)ctrl).Checked)
        {
            switch (((RadioButton)ctrl).Name)
            { 
                case "radioButtonGoodCodeSumm":
                    nCheckedRadioIdx = 0;
                    break;
                case "radioButtonBadCodeSumm":
                    nCheckedRadioIdx = 1;
                    break;
                case "radioButtonBadByEpiNo":
                    nCheckedRadioIdx = 2;
                    break;
                case "radioButtonValidCodes":
                    nCheckedRadioIdx = 3;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I then use an enumerator to establish which button I need. This seems very verbose to me (in fact damn ugly!). I have seen this done in VB with some sort of LINQ query [(SO Question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466952/how-to-get-a-checked-radio-button-in-a-groupbox) but I have never worked with VB or LINQ and am struggling with the conversion. If there is an even better way that would be great as one of the `GroupBox`s contains a significant number of `RadioButton`s - I would like to use LINQ for this if possible?

Comment: The direct translation of that VB.NET code to C# would be something like: `RadioButton rButton = GroupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>.Where(r => r.Checked == true).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Thanks. However, this translation is not quite working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have, for each radiobutton **THE SAME** event handler that, when the button is checked set the Tag property of your GroupBox to the Tag of your RadioButton. At design time you set the Tag of the RadioButton to your desidered enum value. When you wish to retrieve your checked button you have only to read the Tag property without going through a loop (elegant or less) to check every control in your GroupBox.

For example:

```
private void RadioButton_Checked(oject sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton radio = ((RadioButton)sender);
    if(radio.Checked)
        groupBoxList.Tag = radio.Tag;
}
```

Of course this will be efficient, but you should be sure to well document this because a change in the enum change will create problems.

Comment: +1 Thanks good idea. I would like to use LINQ however. For the fun of it! :]

Comment: @Killercam, I like LINQ too, but it seems inefficient in this case.

Comment: I concious of adding this event handler for every `RadioButton`. What is the deal here? Thanks for your time...

Comment: Perhaps I have not spelled my intentions correctly. I think to use one event handler for all the radiobuttons. I mean the same event handler! Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var control in groupBox3.Controls)
{                
    RadioButton radio = control as RadioButton;

    if (radio != null && radio.Checked)
    {
        var a = radio.Name;   //it gives the name of radio button is checked
    }
}
```