# How can I get the true value?

Tags: c#, groupbox

[image]
[image]

This is all the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in groupBox1.Controls)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(control.ToString());
    }
}
```

I only want to get the `true` value
But there is no `Checked`.
How can I get the true value?
How can I get each index?

Comment: what is "the true value"? What result do you **expect** and what do you **get actually**?

Comment: Try casting it to a radio. The base Control class doesn't have a checked property.

Comment: Cast it to RadioButton first, your MessageBox already states what type of control it is

Comment: Control is just controle it can be anything. It cant be checked or unchecked. You should filter to get only the RadioButton. With the Type radio button

Comment: @HimBromBeere: `control.ToString()` contains the text shown in the screen shot, including the "Checked" value (which happens to be `True` in the example). They want that checked value only, but can't find the Checked property (because the control has not been cast yet). Easiest solution is probably `groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()`, but I'll let someone else write that down and collect the rep. :-)

Comment: You need ot be able to enumerate through the radio buttons in the group box. Sometimes I use a List<RadionButton>.  Searching for the radio buttons is slow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which Radio button in the group is checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797907/which-radio-button-in-the-group-is-checked)

Comment: And Vb version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466952/how-to-get-a-checked-radio-button-in-a-groupbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, you have *all* controls, which is why they are of type control and you don't know what they are at compile-time.

Make sure you only get those of type `RadioButton`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RadioButton radioButton in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
    {
         MessageBox.Show(radioButton.Checked.ToString());
    }
}
```