# how to display on a messagebox, which radio button was selected

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have 2 radio button for gender. one male (named `radMale`) one female (name `radFemale`). lets say a user clicks the "male" button. how do i display what he chose on a `MessageBox`?

```
MessageBox.Show(radMale = "Male");
```

I know this doesn't work, does anyone know which code will?

Comment: for winforms you have the [RadioButton.CheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged.aspx) event that you can listen to. But it is as Daniel says, it depends on the technology you use

Comment: its simple, on radMale.click event show messagebox with "Male", and radFemale.click event show messagebox with "Female"...

Comment: Its very basic question. You should read a book first or search for tutorial [Heres one](http://www.functionx.com/vcsharp2003/applications/calc.htm)

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797907/which-radio-button-in-the-group-is-checked

Answer (score 3):

I tried executing the following code which might solve your problem.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
            radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
            radioButton2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
        }

        void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
            if(rb.Checked)
                MessageBox.Show(rb.Text); //Shows whatever Text your radiobutton has
        }

        void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in WinForms, use this:

```
MessageBox.Show(radMale.Checked?"Male":"Female");
```