# how to know which radiobutton is checked?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

i have this part of code: (in the click event of a button)

```
           foreach (RadioButton rb in grbFiltro.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
       {
           if (((RadioButton)rb).Checked)
           {
               switch (true)
               {
                   case rbt1.Checked:
                       //do something
                       break;
                   case rbt2.Checked:
                      //do something
                       break;
                   case rbt3.Checked:
                        //do something
                      break;
               }
           }
       }
```

but there´s a error converting radiobutton to string in ---> case rbt1.Checked

how do i fix this, or what else can i use?

Comment: why use switch case and not if else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797907/which-radio-button-in-the-group-is-checked

Comment: i have more than 3 radiobuttons this an example! of my real code and i prefer switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rb = grbFiltro.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
             .SingleOrDefault(rb => rb.Checked.GetValueOrDefault()) as RadioButton;

if (rb!=null)
    switch (rb.Name)
           {
               case "button1":
                   //do something
                   break;
               case "button2":
                  //do something
                   break;
               case "button3":
                    //do something
                  break;
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 25 buttons so I would probably do something like

```
 IEnumerable<RadioButton> buttons = grbFiltro.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>();
    foreach (var Button in buttons)
    {
         if (Button.Checked)
         {
             //Do Something
         }
     }
```

If you need to do something different with each button then you would have an if / else chain that does based on what you need, but I am guessing you are wanting to store the value selected and do something with that.

Comment: i have more than 3 radiobuttons! 25 exactly

Comment: I was basing it on your above post if you have that many buttons I would probably test them in a list give me a second and I will give you some code

Comment: can I use a switch better than if()??

Comment: Depending on what your trying to do I do not think you would need to chain that statement. Most of the time people just get some kind of value from a radio button and store it in a variable for later use. Basically if you wanted say the string value of a radio button called red. you would just var buttonValue = button.Text. Chaining the case out like that adds a large amount of code you don't necessarily need.

Answer (score 0):

you can also add a listener on CheckedChange and always store the currently selected Radio button in a field. Then you just Need to read that value, once your confirmbutton has been clicked. This is Handy if you have more than 10 radiobuttons

```
private RadioButton selectedButton;

//handler for Radio Buttons.
private void onRadioChange(Object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked)
       this.selectedButton = (RadioButton)sender;
}

// handler for confirm button.
private void confirm(Object sender, EventArgs e){
   MessageBox.show(selectedButton.name + " selected");
}
```

untestet, but the way should work.