# How To Find Checked Radio Button Using Group name My code Attached?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, radio-button, web-controls

i am trying to find the value of checked radio using group name i have method that return it but what should i pass in that method along with group name

method is here,

```
private string getRadioValue(ControlCollection clts, string groupName)
{
    string ret = "";
    foreach (Control ctl in clts)
    {
        if (ctl.Controls.Count != 0)
        {
            if (ret == "")
                ret = getRadioValue(ctl.Controls, groupName);
        }

        if (ctl.ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton")
        {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)ctl;
            if (rb.GroupName == groupName && rb.Checked == true)
                ret = rb.Attributes["Value"];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

i use it like

```
Oc.aProjectSubmited = getRadioValue(RadioButton,"Aps");
```

where Aps is radio group but getting error "invalid argument" on radio button i pass ??

hopes for your suggestion thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are passing `RadioButton`. Your method accepts `ControlCollection`, not a `Control`.

Why not pass this.Controls to pass the whole ControlCollection of the page? Or any other ControlCollection that you might be using to keep that RadioButton you want to check?

Here's an example:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getRadioValue(this.Controls, "Hello");
    }

    private string getRadioValue(ControlCollection clts, string groupName)
    {
        string ret = "";
        foreach (Control ctl in clts)
        {
            if (ctl.Controls.Count != 0)
            {
                if (ret == "")
                    ret = getRadioValue(ctl.Controls, groupName);
            }

            if (ctl.ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton")
            {
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)ctl;
                if (rb.GroupName == groupName && rb.Checked == true)
                    ret = rb.Attributes["Value"];
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a shorter version using Linq to avoid the loops...

```
public static string GetRadioValue(ControlCollection controls, string groupName)
{
   var selectedRadioButton = controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(rb => rb.GroupName == groupName && rb.Checked);
   return selectedRadioButton == null ? string.Empty : selectedRadioButton.Attributes["Value"];
}
```

Comment: Just found a similar answer from SLaks on a similar question...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797907/which-radio-button-in-the-group-is-checked

Comment: The "similar answer" mentioned above relates to WinForms - this is a WebForms question.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ:

```
container.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.GroupName == "GroupName" && r.Checked).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ToString() is not going to give you what you want: You need somthing more like

```
private string getRadioValue(ControlCollection clts, string groupName)
{
    var ret = "";
    foreach (Control ctl in clts)
    {
        if (ctl.Controls.Count != 0)
        {
            ret = getRadioValue(ctl.Controls, groupName);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ret)) {
          return ret;
        }
        var rb = ctl as RadioButton;
        if (rb != null && rb.GroupName == groupName && rb.Checked)
                return = rb.Attributes["Value"];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: well, ToString() will still work although it's not a best practice. I don't think this is the answer though.

Comment: @Bob what should i pass for "ControlCollection clts" ?

Comment: @aiapatag OK didn't check that `RadioButton.ToString()` outputted the class name, however if an inherited control was used that used a different implementation of ToString then my answer would still work

Comment: @BobVale yes indeed. But what I'm saying is... that is not the answer to the poster's question.

Comment: @testerJoe Guessing the value attribute for the found radio button is null or unset.

Comment: if i wanna get id of radio then i would replace ["Value"] by ["Id"] ?

Comment: @testerJoe either `rb.ID` if you want the server side id or `rb.ClientID` if you want the client side id

Comment: @BOb i did the same Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even more shorter version (in my example I needed the Text of the Radio) Button.

You can also make it as an extension method of HtmlGenericControl which would be div for example.

```
public static class HtmlGenericControlExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets selected value of radio button by group name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controls">Html generic control.</param>
    /// <param name="groupName">Name of the button group.</param>
    /// <returns>Selected radio button name.</returns>
    public static string GetSelectedRadioButtonName(this HtmlGenericControl control, string groupName)
        => control.Controls
            .OfType<RadioButton>()
            .FirstOrDefault(rb => rb.GroupName.Equals(groupName) && rb.Checked)?.Text ?? string.Empty;
}
```