# Foreach RadioButtons in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm have `ASP MultiView` for an application form. Inside one of the view I have few radio button as follows--

```
<div class="row">
  <asp:CustomValidator ID="Group1Validator" GroupName="Group1" runat="server"
   ValidationGroup="Group1" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator>
  <asp:RadioButton ID="Group1Yes" runat="server" GroupName="Group1" Text="Yes"/>
  <asp:RadioButton ID="Group1No" runat="server" GroupName="Group1" Text="No" />
</div>
```

Now on the code behind I want to iterate through all the `RadioButtons` in that page and pull the values to be saved in the `DB`.  I have tried the solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832004/how-to-find-checked-radio-button-using-group-name-my-code-attached) both `Loop` and `LINQ` version, but the problem is my RadioButton controls are not directly in the page. Let me elaborate-

First, I have multi view in a page-

[image]

Multi view contains views-

[image]

And finally inside views I have the `RadioButton` controls-

[image]

Now my goal is the fetch the values of all the `RadioButton` that are selected which is laid out using the `div` above.

Any help and guidance will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must put your RadioButtons as childs of RadioButtonList, then iterate in foreach loop over RadioButtonList items.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `RadioButtonList`

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And then you can get the value in code behind

```
string value = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
```

You can also add items to the RadioButtonList in code behind

```
RadioButtonList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Yes", "1", true));
RadioButtonList1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("No", "0", true));
```