# How do I get which radio button is checked from a groupbox?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have these groupboxes:

[image]

I want to run some code according to checked true state of a radio button like:

```
string chk = radiobutton.nme; // Name of radio button whose checked is true
switch(chk)
{
    case "Option1":
        // Some code
        break;

    case "Option2":
        // Some code
        break;

    case "Option3":
        // Some code
        break;
}
```

Is there any direct way so that I can only get the name of the checked radio button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Radio button in the group is checked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797907/which-radio-button-in-the-group-is-checked)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can find all checked RadioButtons like

```
var buttons = this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                           .FirstOrDefault(n => n.Checked);
```

Also take a look at  [`CheckedChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged.aspx) event.

> Occurs when the value of the Checked property changes.

Comment: @Soner I tried to use this code, but it provides a error of ambiguity between ´Forms.RadioButton´ and ´Controls.RadioButton´ , what does it means?

Comment: @CésarAmorim Both `System.Windows.Controls` and `System.Windows.Forms` have `RadioButton` class. I feel like, in your project both these namepsaces are added and compiler confuses which namespace belongs on this `RadioButton` when you type it only it's name. As a solution, you can use it's full name to prevent this situation like `System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton` or `System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton`.

Comment: Had some trouble following this for Universal Windows Apps, as `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page` doesn't have `Controls` property there, so it's best to use some encapsulating WPF element, like named `StackPanel` or `Grid` and `Children` property: `rbPanel.Children.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.IsCheked.Value);`  (`IsChecked` is nullable, hence the `.Value`)

Comment: Would someone be able to explain the .FirstOrDefault(n => n.Checked); line for me please?

Comment: @PaulAlexander `OfType<RadioButton>` method returns `IEnumerable<RadioButton>` which means an iterable collections of `RadioButton`'s. `FirstOrDefault` method returns the first element (or `default` if can't find any element satisfied _that_ condition) which satisfied with given condition, which is `n.Checked` (that means checked) in our case. Based on radio button structure, it can be _only_ one selected item, so this code does exactly what OP wants. For more information, check `Enumerable` class from MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable

Answer (score 10):

```
groupbox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked).Name
```

this will get the name of checked radio button. If you want to use it later, you might store name of that by storing into variable.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You should take some look at the `CheckedChanged` event to register the corresponding event handler and store the `Checked` radio button state in some variable. However, I would like to use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) here just because you have just some `RadioButtons` which makes the cost of looping acceptable:

```
var checkedRadio = new []{groupBox1, groupBox2}
                   .SelectMany(g=>g.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                                            .Where(r=>r.Checked))
// Print name
foreach(var c in checkedRadio)
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(c.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking all RadioButtons, use the Validated event of the GroupBox.

```
private void grpBox_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GroupBox g = sender as GroupBox;
        var a = from RadioButton r in g.Controls where r.Checked == true select r.Name;
        strchecked = a.First();
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, it's better if you use RadioGroup instead of GroupBox. If you use radioGroup, you can always find the selected item easily like this:

```
radioGroup.selectedIndex;
```

If you design using Windows Forms, I suggest to implement RadioGroup behavior like this (please note that my code is in Java):

```
for (Component comp:groupBox1.components) {
    if (((RadioButton)comp).selected)
        return ((RadioButton)comp).value;
}
```

You can put this code block in a method to return selected radioButton value, and then you can use this value in your SWITCH part.

Comment: i am using windows forms and there is no option of radio group