# C# - How do I separately return int values from each radio GroupBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, radio-button

Please allow me to clarify my situation and approach.

***I have an excel file with 10 columns. First five columns have data which form the conditions for the query, while the last five columns contain data which form the result.***

> I am trying to make a software with this data in a database or excel
>   (if database is difficult) where the first five columns will be linked
>   to a List or Menu or presently RadioButtons in five different groups.
>   When the selections are made and SUBMIT button is pressed, the result
>   will be displayed as five data from matching rows in the excel or
>   database.

That is what I am trying to achieve.

Please comment if my approach is wrong. Thanks in advance to all the posts.

--------------------------Original Question----------------------------

I have 5 groupboxes(1 has 5 radiobuttons, 2 has 3, 3 and 4 has 11, and 5 has 4 ) on a WPF.
Based on which radiobutton is selected from each groupBox, the software is expected to give four parameters output (from a CSV or a database)

I have used [How do I get which radio button is checked from a groupbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547326/how-do-i-get-which-radio-button-is-checked-from-a-groupbox) the code from this given by King King, and modified it to use for my purpose.

```
var checkedRadio = new []{groupBox1, groupBox2, groupBox3, groupBox4, groupBox5}.SelectMany(g=>g.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(r=>r.Checked));
foreach(var c in checkedRadio)
    MessageBox.Show(c.Name);
```

What this gives me is the radiobuttons selected one after another as message box.

I want to thank King King, and the many others (more than 20) whose answers for various answers helped me reach this point.

Where I am stuck is **how to use the foreach loop to assign values to five separate int and then use it to calculate a final int value** which I can assign to various results I want to display.

I tried to assign values to int in each CheckedChanged event handler but all of them are private void and not returning anything. I tried to change them to return ints but I can't seem to crack that nut.

I am sure my whole approach could be wrong here, but I have not much idea in this.

//What I basically want is to give options in g=five groups, and based on selections from these five groups (columns in an excel), display results from 4 corresponding columns in the matching row in a database. My present approach above is a workaround since I have no knowledge of working with databases.//

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should *omit* assigning values to *five separated* `int`s, but compute the resulting value. For instance, let's encode `groupBox`s by bits, and compute a *bit mask*

```
  groupBox1 - 00001 (let it be checked)
  groupBox2 - 00010   
  groupBox3 - 00100 (let it be checked)   
  groupBox4 - 01000 (let it be checked)  
  groupBox5 - 10000
  -----------------
  mask        01101 (13)
```

so if `groupBox1`, `groupBox3` and `groupBox4` are *checked* the final mask will be `01101`

```
var result = new [] {groupBox1, groupBox2, groupBox3, groupBox4, groupBox5}
  .Select((box, index) => new {
    box = box,
    mask = 1 << index
  }) 
  .Where(item => item.box.Controls
    .OfType<RadioButton>()
    .Any(button => button.Checked))
  .Sum(item => item.mask);
```

In case you have to use *arbitrary weights* organize them into a *collection* e.g., array

```
  double[] weights = new double[] {1.2, 3.58, 4.62, -1.7, 0.9};

  double result = new [] {groupBox1, groupBox2, groupBox3, groupBox4, groupBox5}
    .Select((box, index) => new {
       box = box,
       weight = weights[index] 
     }  
    .Where(item => item.box.Controls
       .OfType<RadioButton>()
       .Any(button => button.Checked))
    .Sum(item => item.weight);
```

The guiding principle remains the same: do not use *separated values*: since you have a *collection* for controls (groupboxes), put corresponding values into a *collection* as well

Comment: This makes sense. I am extremely grateful for your input. The situation is that, there must be one selection from each group box, and I need to know each selection. For this, will adding a unique int to each help?Because otherwise, the selection doesn't help me narrow down to the individual radiobutton.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but that's ugly having separate collections. You should either make a user control based on the checkbox that has the int, or use the tag of the control. You could have the group box as a control that abstracts the calculations to the form but that would depend on what else you do with them.

```
public class MyClass : CheckBox 
{
    public int MyValue { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {

    }
}
```

Or just use:

```
value = (int)myCheckBox.Tag;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is much helpful. I understand the problem with the multiple collections, but my choice was for a cosmetic reason of clubbing similar options together. Let me try otherwise.