# How to insert radiobuttons into SQL Server database? radio buttons are in a group box in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, groupbox

I have two group boxes in which I have by 3 radio buttons and I want the selected value of the radio button to be inserted in the database.

I use this below code but its not working. Regarding the table, I have only one row for this value to be inserted

```
sqlDataAdapter1.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@n", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.groupKamera.Checked.ToString();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get which radio button is checked from a groupbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547326/how-do-i-get-which-radio-button-is-checked-from-a-groupbox)

Answer (score -1):

In case to save the radio button name

```
var selectedRadioButton = groupKamera.Controls
   .OfType<RadioButton>()
   .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Checked);

sqlDataAdapter1.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@n", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.selectedRadioButton.ID;
```

Comment: This isn't VB.Net and I don't think `Name` of radio button is what OP is looking for.