# How to link between class and GUI C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, radio-button

I have created a class and have coded for the radio button on the class and would like to link it to a code on the GUI button is it possible ? The GUI used is Windows form application

Code for the class

```
public void OnlineSalesman(double OnlinePercentage,  double OnlineSales)
    {
        double Commission = OnlinePercentage * OnlineSales;
        double Total = Commission + OnlineSales;
        Message = Commission.ToString();
        Message1 = Total.ToString();
    }

    public void PhoneSalesman(double PhonePercentage, double PhoneSales)
    {
        double Comission = PhonePercentage * PhoneSales;
        double Total = Comission + PhoneSales;
        Message = Comission.ToString();
        Message1 = Total.ToString();
    }

    public void DoorSalesman(double DoorPercentage, double DoorSales)
    {
        double Comission = DoorPercentage * DoorSales;
        double Total = Comission + DoorSales;
        Message = Comission.ToString();
        Message1 = Total.ToString();
    }
```

Code for the button on the GUI that i want to add the class radio button code into

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double sales = 0;

        if (txtID.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter ID");
            txtID.Focus();
        }
        else if (txtSales.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Sales");
            txtSales.Focus();
        }
        else if (txtName.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Name ");
        }

        else if (double.TryParse(txtSales.Text, out sales) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Numeric Value only");
            txtSales.Focus();
        }

        else
        {
           if (the codes i want to link from the class)
        }
    }
```

Comment: which language? which framework?

Comment: Are you using MVC, WebForms, what?

Comment: Windows form application

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: i have shown it in my question @sr28 .

Comment: What you meant by coded for radio button? Is it code for radio button events and you want to use that code in button click? Please provide bit more details.

Comment: So, you basically want to add a radio button in and add an else statement that will use it's values, is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes that is what i wanted to do :)

Comment: Ok, so have you added a radio button onto your form? Here's an example of how to wire them up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797907/which-radio-button-in-the-group-is-checked Note, this is for a radio button group.