# wpf RadioButton - get wheter first time selected

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, radio-button

Let's say we have a couple of `RadioButton` objects (all: not selected) and we select one of them.

So what I want to know is; how to determine whether we had a `RadioButton` selected or not. How can I acheive this in c#?

Comment: Use binding or Checked event.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1797955/6170142). If all radio buttons are not selected, this should return null. If its null then you never selected any of those radio buttons.

Comment: thanks a lot @krw12572 that is the key to the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if any radio button is checked as follows;

```
var checkedButton = container.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
```

If `checkedButton` remains **null** then that means you have never selected any of these radio buttons.

In wpf, try following;

```
 var checkedButton = container.Children.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => (bool)r.IsChecked);
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1797955/6170142) for more description.

Comment: that is fine if I would call it outside of the CheckedEvent. Calling it inside the CheckedEvent throws still [wrong] result (true result, but not the intended).

Comment: Well, you could call it on Page shown event and store its result in some field. Then you could access that field in your CheckedEvent.

Comment: at the moment I store the value in the Parents TagProperty, but to store it in a field would also be a solution.