# Determine if check status for radiobutton group has changed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a group of 8 radiobuttons, is there a simple way to check if "checked" status has changed for the group? I don't need to know which button has been checked, just if a different button has been checked. Sort of like a CheckedChanged event for the whole group.

Comment: No, but it easy to implement a simple variable that is set to false after the initial load and set to true if any of the radiobuttons fire the CheckedChanged event

Comment: Hanlde `CheckedChanged` of all radio buttons using a single method.

Comment: try using if(radioButton1.checked) and in aspx file fire CheckChanged event.. This question is Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797907/which-radio-button-in-the-group-is-checked?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign the same `CheckedChanged` event handler to all of the radiobuttons. When you check a radiobutton, the method will be called twice (for the radiobutton losing the checkmark and for the radiobutton being checked). So only handle the event for the one that is checked.

```
  private void anyRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       // The radio button that raised the event
       var radioButton = sender as RadioButton;

       // Only do something when the event was raised by the radiobutton 
       // being checked, so we don't do this twice.
       if(radioButton.Checked)
       {
            // Do something here 
       }
  }
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks to everyone for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is this, a common handler for all radio buttons in the group

```
radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButtons_CheckedChanged);
radioButton2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButtons_CheckedChanged);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wire up all of the RadioButtons' CheckedChanged event to the same handler.  Follow this code.

```
public Form1()
    {
        rB1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rB_CheckedChanged);
        rB2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rB_CheckedChanged);


    }

    private void rB_CheckedChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = sender as RadioButton;

        if (rB1.Checked)
        {

        }
        else if (rB2.Checked)
        {

        }
    }
```